# HTML cannot load css and js file in iOS/OSX project

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, macos

it work perfect when the css and javascript write in the HTML file, but it is not working after extracting the javascript code to a separate file. have some way to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Get it, We do not need to add the detail path to load the js/css file. No matter which folder u put your css/js file, just do like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your.css">
<script src="your.js"></script>
```

don't do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/your.css">
<script src="js/your.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `www` has sub-folders, when drag it into Xcode, make sure select `Create folder references for any added folders`. This option will keep `www` structure. js/css files will loaded successfully.